# Start with page two in LaTeX book

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

I need to not have a page number for title but my second page should start with roman numeral 2. I tried

```
\setcounter{page}{1}
\thispagestyle{empty}
```

but it would not work and it hides the page number for title page but it does not start with page 2 afterwards.

Comment: please post a complete small document that shows the problem. Currently all we can say is that there is an error in some code you have not shown.

Comment: You don't need to \setcounter. The first page is automatically given the page number 1 whether it is printed or not. The only time you might need this is if, for example, you need to restart page numbering later in the document.

Comment: Yes thanks. I found that at the beginning of the first page need to put \thispagestyle{empty} and at the end of the second page put \pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{2}